# Detect data imbalance in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, imbalanced-data, imblearn

Is there is any method to check if there is data imbalance beforehand, something like:

```py
balanced = check_balance(y)
```

Where `y` is the array that contains the categories to predict, and it returns `True` or `False` indicating if the data needs to be balanced or not, taking into account that the number of unique categories in y is not fixed (we use the same model structure for different datasets), it may be a binary classification or multiclass.

Comment: You have to check that yourself by plotting it: `df['target'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')`

Comment: Yes, I do make that kind of check, I'm just looking for some automated rule to make this check and automate the whole workflow